# How to stretch column from nav-bar to bottom of window?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, multiple-columns

I'm trying to stretch a column from the bottom of the nav bar to the bottom of the window.

But I'm running into 2 undesirable situations.

1. Column only takes up as much space as elements inside it
   [image]
2. Column stretches entire height of window but covers up part of the nav bar
   [image]

CSS

```
@media (min-width: 768px){
#left {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 25%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

#right {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 75%;
}
```

}

View/Users/Show

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="tabbable">
            <ul id="left" class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked col-md-3" style="padding-right: 50px;">
                <%= render 'lists/form' %>
                <% @lists.each do |list| %>
                    <%= content_tag :li  do %>
                            <a href="#list-<%=list.id %>" data-toggle="tab"><%= list.name %></a>
                    <% end %>
                <% end %>
            </ul>

        <div id="right" class="tab-content col-md-9">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Views/Layouts/Application.html.erb

```
<body>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" style="margin: 0">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <% if current_user %>
          <%= link_to "App Name", @user, class: 'navbar-brand' %>
        <% else %>
          <%= link_to "App Name", root_path, class: 'navbar-brand' %>
        <% end %>
      </div>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  </div>
  <% end %>

    <%= yield %>

</body>
```

Bootstrap and ruby on rails are being used.

**I'm new to web design. Would be amazing if someone can point me in the right direction?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this css (jsfiddle example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ymqrg278/)):

```
html, body, .container, .row, .tabbable{height:100%}
#left {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 25%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: calc(100% - 20px);
}

#right {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
}
```

, where `#right` div should come before `#left` div.

And if you want to position them `absolute`,

```
 html, body, .container, .row, .tabbable{height:100%}
    #left {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 25%;
        overflow-y: scroll;
        height: calc(100% - 20px);
        margin-top:20px;//height of #right
    }

    #right {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        right: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 20px;
    }
```

, and it's not important in which order the html divs come.